# Move text down a line in a HREF

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my text in the exact middle of my anchor but it isn't doing it.

I have no idea what to do, I've tried changing the padding but that simply did nothing

Screenshot:http://prntscr.com/gvra9h

```css
#navbar ul {
  color: #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  color: #000;
  float: right;
}

#navbar li a {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #74CCFF;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: #4400FF;
}

#navbar li a#contact {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Include your least minimal `HTML` so that others can help you with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your nav items have a static height, you can just use a line-height that matches the height. As long as your link text is always just one line, it'll be centered.

```
#navbar li a {
 height: 52px;
 line-height: 52px;
}
```

---

Sample:

```css
#navbar ul {
  color: #000;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  color: #000;
  float: right;
}

#navbar li a {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  background-color: #74CCFF;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: #4400FF;
}

#navbar li a#contact {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="contact" href="#" alt="Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="about" href="#" alt="About">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
a {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

if that doesn't align in the center, than add a `<p>` after your `<a>` and in css do:

```
a p {
position: relative; 
top:50%; left:50%; 
transform:translate(-50%, -50%;)
}
```

This is a good solution because regardless of the size of your `<div>` it will automatically move to the center, and you can also add multiple lines of text.